# Gradle create javadoc including subproject sources

Tags: gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
API/
└── client/
    ├── subA/
    │   └── build.gradle
    ├── subB/
    │   └── build.gradle
    └── build.gradle
```

And the following build.gradle inside client subproject:

```groovy
task clientApiDocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    destinationDir = reporting.file("javadoc")
    classpath = configurations.compile
    options.tags = ["stereotype"]
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
}

assemble.dependsOn(clientApiDocs)

distributions {
    main {
        contents{
            from (clientApiDocs.outputs) {
                into 'javadoc/ClientJava'
            }
        }
    }
    createStartScripts {
        applicationName = 'ClientJava'
    }
}
```

My goal is to include javadoc from subprojects subA and subB inside clientApiDocs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The awesome `io.freefair` plugin collection provides a plugin called [`io.freefair.aggregate-javadoc`](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/current/reference/#_io_freefair_aggregate_javadoc) that should suit your needs:

> This plugin adds a `aggregateJavadoc` task to the project which will generate the aggregated javadoc for the project itself and all of its subprojects (which have the `java` plugin applied).

Just add the following code to the `build.gradle` file of your root project. Choose a version based on the compatibility matrix in the [project `README`](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/blob/master/README.md).

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'io.freefair.aggregate-javadoc' version <version>
}
```

Internally, the plugin uses a regular task of type `Javadoc`. It gets configured using the [following code](https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/blob/master/maven-plugin/src/main/java/io/freefair/gradle/plugins/maven/javadoc/AggregateJavadocPlugin.java):

```groovy
project.allprojects(p ->
    p.getPlugins().withType(JavaPlugin.class, jp ->
        aggregateJavadoc.configure(aj -> {
            TaskProvider<Javadoc> javadoc = p.getTasks().named(JavaPlugin.JAVADOC_TASK_NAME, Javadoc.class);

            aj.source(javadoc.map(Javadoc::getSource));

            if (aj.getClasspath() instanceof ConfigurableFileCollection) {
                ((ConfigurableFileCollection) aj.getClasspath()).from(javadoc.map(Javadoc::getClasspath));
            }
            else {
                ConfigurableFileCollection classpath = project.files();
                classpath.from(aj.getClasspath());
                classpath.from(javadoc.map(Javadoc::getClasspath));
                aj.setClasspath(classpath);
            }

            StandardJavadocDocletOptions options = (StandardJavadocDocletOptions) javadoc.get().getOptions();
            StandardJavadocDocletOptions aggregateOptions = (StandardJavadocDocletOptions) aj.getOptions();

            options.getLinks().forEach(link -> {
                if (!aggregateOptions.getLinks().contains(link)) {
                    aggregateOptions.getLinks().add(link);
                }
            });
            options.getLinksOffline().forEach(link -> {
                if (!aggregateOptions.getLinksOffline().contains(link)) {
                    aggregateOptions.getLinksOffline().add(link);
                }
            });
            options.getJFlags().forEach(jFlag -> {
                if (!aggregateOptions.getJFlags().contains(jFlag)) {
                    aggregateOptions.getJFlags().add(jFlag);
                }
            });
        })
    )
);
```